# Как выбрать приоритетное сетевое соединение?

Tags: сеть, linux

Суть такова. Есть подключение wi-fi, которое привносить в жизнь интернет, и есть Ethernet подключение по кабелю, по которому осуществляется расшаривание папок и файлов между двумя машинами. Но два соединения одновременно не уживаются ни в какую - либо отваливается интернет, либо отваливается файловый обмен. Как быть?

Comment: Адрес сети на кабеле должен отличаться от адреса wifi, сконфигурируйте сеть на кабеле без default routing (без шлюза)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала у  сетей должны быть разные сегменты, как минимум, а то пакеты заколцевать можете. Во-вторых, возможно с метрикой конфликты. В-третьих, проверьте шлюзы, правильно ли вы их прописали? Проверьте еще, таблицы маршрутизации.